# In one of my operation on updating list in Python, I am getting unexpected result? Explain Please

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to update the list in other scenario other than using map function. I tried loop and on one of my operation, I get unexpected result. Here is my code.

```
    #my_function_which_is_only_for_printing
    def app(l):
        for i in l:
            print(i)

    l=[1,2,'3','4'] #list_with_int_and_str
    app(l) #calling_function

    #As result my all output are integer
    #It Should be integer and character rather then all as integer
```

My Expected output is like this
1
2
3
4
And I should get it like this
1
2
'3'
'4'

Comment: '3' and '4' are strings while 1 and 2 are integers, and that is exactly what the function prints.

Comment: to get `'3'` printed as `'3'` you can use `repr`: `print(repr(i))`

Comment: when you print a string, it doesn't print any quotation marks, unless actually *contained* in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is doing what you want: 1 and 2 are of `int` type and '3' and '4' are of `str` type:

```
def app(l):
    for i in l:        
        print("{} is: {}".format(i, type(i)))

l = [1,2,'3','4']

app(l)

1 is: <class 'int'>
2 is: <class 'int'>
3 is: <class 'str'>
4 is: <class 'str'>
```

**Edit**: To get string representation of the `list` elements, like @Paul Panzer suggested in the comments, you could do `print(repr(i))`:

```
def app(l):
    for i in l:        
        print(repr(i), end=' ') # Print on the same line

l = [1,2,'3','4']

app(l)

1 2 '3' '4' 
>>>
```

[repr(*object*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) says:

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object.

Comment: But, when we use to print string, then result should always comes out with ' '.

Comment: But see if I try this one- 
l=[1,2,'3','4']
print(l)
so the result are like this
[1,2,'3','4']

Comment: Your question here is about printing individual elements of a list. Please ask a new question regarding this.